# What's the complexity of this algorithm

Tags: c++, complexity-theory

What is the time complexity of this algorithm?

```
void prime(int n) { 
    int i = 2;
    while ((n % i) && i <= sqrt(n))
        i++;

    if (i > sqrt(n))
        print(“%d is a prime number\n”, n);
    else
        print(“%d is not a prime number\n”, n);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `n` being prime or not prime would change the complexity?

Comment: yap, I know the complexity won't  change no matter n is prime or not. So I have no idea about its complexity.

Comment: So what exactly are you asking? Your comment directly contradicts the first line of your question.

Comment: If you restrict it to the domain of non-prime positive integers, you are guaranteed to terminate early at the smaller factor, which could be (worst case) sqrt(sqrt(n)). So yes, it would change.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity is approximately O(sqrt(N)). Some books will express that as O(N<sup>0.5</sup>).

The square root is re-computed each iteration of the loop. This is a fairly slow operation, so it's slower than optimal, but only by a constant factor, so it doesn't affect the computational complexity.

Comment: Since it is a c++ fixed size integer, yes. Although sqrt need not be constant if it had been e.g. python, or a large integer type from a math library.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I was thinking wrong. 
Hey it is simply O(sqrt(n))...
Look the while contion executes for all x<=sqrt(n) which divides n. So i can atmost run O(sqrt(n)) times. So yea it is O(sqrt(n)). No other factors involved.

Comment: @Vincent_Bryan:: sorry for making it like that earllier... check my answer now. It is sqrt(n).

Comment: I think O(sqrt(n)) is the worse case, what's the average case?